# C# - Converting a float to an int... and changing the int depending on the remainder

Tags: c#, type-conversion

This is probably a really newbie question (well, I'm pretty sure it is), but I have a **float** that's being returned and I need a quick and efficient way of turning it into an **int**.

Pretty simple, but I have an exception. If the remainder of the **float** is anything other than .0 then I want to increment the **int**.

Some quick examples:

Float = 98.0, Int = 98
Float = 98.1, Int = 99
Float = 6.6, Int = 7
etc.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This should do it:

```
int myInt = (int)Math.Ceiling(myFloat);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
Math.Ceiling();
```

as Math.Round() won't make 98.1 equal to 99

Answer (score 4):

```
Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(FloatValue));
```