# c# how to convert float to int

Tags: c#, floating-point, int

I need to convert float to int (single precision, 32 bits) like:
'float: 2 (hex: 40000000) to int: 1073741824'. Any idea how to implement that?
I was looking for it in msdn help but with no result.

Comment: [link] http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html

Comment: In effect, you want a bit-wise copy? Like C++'s reinterpret_cast?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578348/c-converting-a-float-to-an-int-and-changing-the-int-depending-on-the-remain

Comment: I'm not sure convert is the right verb.

Comment: @castleofbones: that link is to conversions that preserve the represented number. The OP is after a conversion that preserves the binary representation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your aiming for versions less than .Net 4 where BitConverter isn't available, or you want to convert floats to 32 bit ints, use a memory stream:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Stream
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main (string [] args)
    {
      float
        f = 1;

      int
        i;

      MemoryStream
        s = new MemoryStream ();

      BinaryWriter
        w = new BinaryWriter (s);

      w.Write (f);

      s.Position = 0;

      BinaryReader
        r = new BinaryReader (s);

      i = r.ReadInt32 ();

      s.Close ();

      Console.WriteLine ("Float " + f + " = int " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

It is a bit long winded though.

Answer (score 10):

```
float f = ...;
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

[BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits.aspx), as per the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c).

If the above solution is no good for you (due to it acting upon `double`/`Double` rather than `float`/`Single`) then see [David Heffernan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173677/c-how-to-convert-float-to-int/7174005#7174005).

Comment: question is about 4 byte float and int

Answer (score 1):

David THANKS, that was a short answer of my long search of analogue for Java method: Float.floatToIntBits. Here is the entire code:

```
static void Main()
{

    float tempVar = -27.25f;

    int intBits = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(tempVar), 0);
    string input = Convert.ToString(intBits, 2);
    input = input.PadLeft(32, '0');
    string sign = input.Substring(0, 1);
    string exponent = input.Substring(1, 8);
    string mantissa = input.Substring(9, 23);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Sign = {0}", sign);
    Console.WriteLine("Exponent = {0}", exponent);
    Console.WriteLine("Mantissa = {0}", mantissa);
}
```