# i do not know how to convert from 'float' to 'int'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i'm learning programming , and i'm stuck on this error for a long time

i tried changing variable to float

```
        Color col;
        float red, green, blue,gray;

        for (int i = 0; i < oImage.Width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < oImage.Height; j++)
            {
                col = oImage.GetPixel(i, j);
                red = col.R;
                green = col.G;
                blue = col.B;
                gray = red*0.21 + green*0.72 + blue*0.07;


             oImage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray));

            }

        picImage.Refresh();
```

i expect the output is to convert a normal photo to a luminosity background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# how to convert float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173677/c-sharp-how-to-convert-float-to-int)

Comment: For the casual reader it would be nice to know what goes wrong: Do you get a compiler error? Do you get a runtime error? Or does the program compile and run but does not produce the expected result?

Comment: I also frown upon questions which are easily googleable. When I google "c# convert float to int" I get a number of useful answers. Among them (admittedly at rank 12) is the [canonical documentation from microsoft.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions): "There exists a conversion between any two numeric types, either implicit or explicit. You must use the cast operator () to invoke an explicit conversion." ... "**Explicit numeric conversions:** ... From float  to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, or decimal".

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
gray = red*0.21 + green*0.72 + blue*0.07;
....
oImage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray));
```

with

```
gray = red * 0.21f + green * 0.72f + blue * 0.07f;
...
oImage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((int)gray, (int)gray, (int)gray));
```

- `0.21` is recognized as double. If you add a `f` it will mark the value as `float`
  [Reference:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

> The literal without suffix or with the d or D suffix is of type double
>
> The literal with the f or F suffix is of type float
>
> The literal with the m or M suffix is of type decimal

- float can be casted into `int` so `(int)myFloatValue` works

Comment: @tymtam for that I cast the `gray` into `int` when calling `FromArgb` - the `green*0.72` gives a compiler error aswell, that's why I mentioned both errors

Comment: Why would you make the literals float? What's the benefit?

Answer (score 0):

You should make `gray` a `byte` and explicitly cast the formula to `byte`.

```
byte gray = (byte) (red*0.21 + green*0.72 + blue*0.07);
```

Please note the restriction on the values passed to [`FromArgb(Int32, Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.8)

> (...) Although this method allows a 32-bit value to be passed for each color component, the value of each component is limited to 8 bits.

---

## Note 1. `bytes`, `floats`, `doubles`, and `ints`

You declare `red`, `green`, `blue` as `float`s where in fact they're `bytes`.

They don't need to be `floats` because a `float`/`double` * a `byte` becomes a `float`/`double`.

Consider the following snippet.

```
Color col = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Salmon);
var red = col.R;
var xR = 0.21;
var grayR = col.R*xR;
```

This prints

```
'red' is System.Byte: 250
'xR' is System.Double: 0.21
'grayR' is System.Double: 52.5
```

## Note 2. Less variables

You can simplify the code by using the RGB values directly in the formula.

```
Color col = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Salmon);
byte gray = (byte) (col.R*0.21 + col.G*0.72 + col.B*0.07);
Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(gray, gray, gray);
```

Comment: thank you soo much.My error was "cannot implicity convert type 'double' to 'float'.".i change the variable to double instead of float .And i do this "oImage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((int)gray, (int)gray, (int)gray));" it works, thx for sovling my problem