# Cast Data Bindings Values Types

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, casting

I have a `Slider` control and a `TextBlock` that shows the value of the `Slider` via data binding.

The problem is that it displays a float and I'm interested in an integer.

I want to cast the float to an integer so instead of seeing `45.25139664804483` in the `TextBlock`, I'll just see `45`.

Comment: Did you try something like `int newValue = Convert.ToInt32(floatValue);`?

Comment: Yes, Tim is right.
Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578348/c-sharp-converting-a-float-to-an-int-and-changing-the-int-depending-on-the

Comment: @Tim I did, but the UI didn't know when the value was updated. It started at 0, and after the slider's value changed, the TextBlock's text stayed at 0.

Comment: Ah...that's a different question.  You need to update the TextBox contents, probably with an event handler.  Post your code and you'll get good answers.  Heh - like the ones below that came in while I was typing this comment the first time :)

Comment: Oh, I aim for a solution that involves data-binding. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible to set your TickFrequency to an integer (e.g. 1) and set IsSnapToTickEnabled = true?

Comment: If you have to have float values, then the only way I can think of is to use a value converter. There's an example at this link (not tested) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/25f2acd1-570b-4c8b-814f-a16985054e89/

Comment: @failedprogramming I think your solution is just perfect! I'll test it.

Comment: @Ken, you can use `StringFormat` on your binding (answer below), simple :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StringFormat` on your `TextBlock` binding to format away the decimal places

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider, StringFormat={}{0:0}}" />
    <Slider x:Name="slider" />
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: God I've tried using the StringFormat so many times but couldn't figure out what to write after the colon. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, StringFormat in xaml is horrible to use, the trick I have fornd is to start it with `{}` seems keep intelisense from flipping out ,LOL, oh and anothet trick is if you need to use NewLine or some othet escape char like that use its Hex value e.g: NewLine = `&#x0a;`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 SO should have a "Stalk" feature, so I can stalk your answers and learn more lol

Comment: @failedprogramming, you can access peoples answers in thier profile, I stalk a lot of people, LOL

Answer (score 2):

Try this on `Slider_ValueChanged`

```
textBox.Value = (int)Math.Ceiling(45.25139664804483);
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with Data Binding?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Slider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
 {
      myTextBlock.Text = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(e.NewValue));
 }
```

Hope this helps.
With Binding:

```
int _myValue;
public int MyValue{get{return _myValue;}set{_myValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue");}}

  private void Slider_ValueChanged_1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
     {
          MyValue = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(e.NewValue));
     }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
```

in this case your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with Data Binding?

Comment: Bind your TextBlock to MyValue. You may wanna see the INotifyPropertyChanged.